# Change an order's website in a multi-website installation

Tags: admin, orders

In a multi-website (some sort of marketplace let's say) I'm looking for a way to change the website related to an order.

When editing an order in **Sales / Orders**, we can see that a website is attached to any order.

I'm looking for an easy way to CHANGE (I mean "reattribute") the order to another website.

First I was considering the "duplicate" option, trying to alter the code and change the website during the process but I didn't manage to do it correctly.

So here I come, seeking for some clues.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it from the UI.
Try this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$order->setStoreId($storeId); //set one of your store view ids from the website you need
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer from @marius is partially correct, but to update all the related data, you'll need to get the order items and invoice as well. e.g.

```
$iNewStoreId = 6;
$oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($iYourOrderEntityId);
foreach($oOrder->getItemsCollection() as $oItem){
  $oItem->setStoreId($iNewStoreId)->save();
}
$oInvoice = $oOrder->getInvoiceCollection()->getFirstItem();
$oInvoice->setStoreId($iNewStoreId)->save();
$oOrder->setStoreId($iNewStoreId)->save();
```

note that the ID to load the order is the `entity_id` not the increment ID which is the public facing order number e.g. 100001234